# Correct usage of 'dashed hopes'

Tags: idioms

> "I sigh, having all hopes to stall dashed."

Is this a correct usage of 'dashed hopes'? If not, how could I better show this person's inner struggle as she resigns herself to her fate?

Comment: Seems fine to me.  It states you had "hoped to stall" (whatever that means) but were not able to.

Answer (score 3):

While the sentence in the question is correct, and so is the one in Jesse Williams' answer, I believe a more normal way of saying this would be:

> I sigh, having all hope of stalling dashed.

Comment: I thought the idiom was 'dashed hopes', as in plural 'hopes'?

Comment: A single hope can also be dashed. Replacing 'hope' with 'hopes' in the above sentence would also be grammatical, but not necessary.

Comment: @DJClayworth - that IS better.  Kudos!